# Dar um valor para input radio não selecionado

Tags: php

Colegas.

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
$array = array("A","B","C","D","E");
    for($contar = 1; $contar <= 9; $contar++){
        echo "Pergunta " . $contar . "<br>";
        foreach($array as $opcao) {
            echo $opcao . ": <input type='radio' name='respostas[".$contar."]' value='" . $opcao ."'>" . "<br>";
        }       
    }
```

E estou pegando os valores dessa forma:

```
    for($contar = 1; $contar <= 9; $contar++){  
      foreach($respostas as $resposta){
           if(!empty($resposta[$contar])){
             $valor = "1";
           }else{
             $valor = "0";
           }
       }
    }
}
```

Preciso fazer com que os campos que não forem selecionados, recebessem o valor 0, porém quando preencho os campos, ele triplica e não fica na ordem correta.

Comment: Amigo eu acredito que se você fizer desta forma é mais eficiente: foreach ($_POST["respostas"] as $value) { switch (trim($value)) { case "": case null: $valor = 0; break; default: $valor = 1; } echo $valor; } Os motivos é pelo `foreach` ser mais apropriado para isso, ele no caso vai fazer a verificação de todos automaticamente, até mesmo se novos valores forem adicionados você não necessita fazer a modificação no código, que no caso seria necessário com o uso do `for`. O uso do `switch` também em comparação ao `if` _neste caso_ é mais apropriado, da pra você fazer a filtragem melhor e mais org

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amigo eu acredito que se você fizer desta forma é mais eficiente:

```
foreach ($_POST["respostas"] as $value) {
    switch (trim($value)) {
        case "":
        case null:
            $valor = 0;
            break;
        default:
            $valor = 1;
    }
    echo $valor;
}
```

Os motivos é pelo `foreach` ser mais apropriado para isso, ele no caso vai fazer a verificação de todos automaticamente, até mesmo se novos valores forem adicionados você não necessita fazer a modificação no código, que no caso seria necessário com o uso do `for`.

O uso do `switch` também em comparação ao `if` *neste caso* é mais apropriado, da pra você fazer a filtragem melhor e mais organizadamente.

Eu utilizei o `trim` para evitar que espaços no início e no final sejam adicionados, um exemplo que poderia sair é este: `" "`

Answer (score 0):

Tanta fazer da seguinte forma abaixo usando estrutura de condição `if` de uma linha, para selecionar o input radio:

```
<input type='radio' <?php if ($opcao == '1') echo 'checked'; ?> name='respostas[".$c."]' value='true'>" . "<br>";
```

Ou também de forma mais simples usando operador termário:

```
<input type='radio' <?php echo $opcao == '1' ? 'checked' : ''; ?> name='respostas[".$c."]' value='true'>" . "<br>";
```

Lembrando que para funcionar qualquer uma das duas soluções acima, a variável `$opcao` tem que ser do tipo `booleana` (true ou false).

Comment: Olá Yure. Tentei usar da forma como você mencionou, porém está deixando marcado toda a última opção selecionada.

Comment: A variável $opcao contem que tipo de valor? Você poderia compara-lo no contação boolean, por exemplo: if ($opcao == '1') echo 'checked';

Comment: Olá Yure. Tem razão. Esqueci de colocar os valores da $opcao. Editei minha dúvida. Ela retorna A,B,C,D e E.

Answer (score 0):

Colegas. Consegui. Segue abaixo a resposta correta:

```
for($contar = 0; $contar <= 9; $contar++){
   if($_POST["respostas"][$contar] != ""){
     $valor = "1";
   }else{
     $valor = "0";
   }
  echo $valor;
}
```

Dessa forma, ele ordena corretamente e mostra os valores conforme seu preenchimento. Ex.:

```
1
0
0
1
0
0
```